# Relational Operators Issue With Null

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am having issues with the below select statement not picking up the data when I insert a relational operator.

```
SELECT C.FIRST_NAME, C.LAST_NAME, B.COMPANY,A.ITEMNO, A.REV, A.DESCRIP
FROM  ARINVT A
INNER JOIN ARCUSTO B 
  ON A.ARCUSTO_ID = B.ID
INNER JOIN PR_EMP C 
  ON B.AR_PR_EMP_ID = C.ID
WHERE A.ARCUSTO_ID = B.ID AND
  B.AR_PR_EMP_ID = C.ID AND
  A.ONHAND <= 0 AND
  A.CUSER7 = 'Y' AND
  A.PK_HIDE <> 'Y'
```

If I remove the last line of the statement (A.PK_HIDE <> 'Y') it picks up the data I am expecting to see. The PK_HIDE column has only 3 different values in the column, 'Y', 'N' or Null. When removing the last line I pick up the data set where PK_HIDE = 'N'.

I have also tried this statement:

```
SELECT C.FIRST_NAME, C.LAST_NAME, B.COMPANY,A.ITEMNO, A.REV, A.DESCRIP
FROM  ARINVT A
INNER JOIN ARCUSTO B 
  ON A.ARCUSTO_ID = B.ID
INNER JOIN PR_EMP C 
  ON B.AR_PR_EMP_ID = C.ID
WHERE A.ARCUSTO_ID = B.ID AND
  B.AR_PR_EMP_ID = C.ID AND
  A.ONHAND <= 0 AND
  A.CUSER7 = 'Y' AND
  A.PK_HIDE = 'N' OR A.PK_HIDE IS NULL
```

That statement seems to ignore `(A.CUSER7 = 'Y')` as it pulls all data sets with `A.PK_HIDE = 'N'` OR `A.PK_HIDE IS NULL`.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need parentheses if you are going to use `OR` with `AND`.

Comment: Precedence of logical operators `AND` and `OR`. For some reason, people think it is OK to work in the computing industry without knowing that. I don't understand it. People who don't know the precedence of addition v multiplication (and correct use of parentheses for that) would never get a job in engineering or accounting.

Comment: Well, use either `(A.PK_HIDE = 'N' OR A.PK_HIDE IS NULL)` *in parentheses* or `nvl(A.PK_HIDE,'N') = 'N'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want manage correctly null value in the first query you should use  a NVL for PK_HIDE

```
SELECT C.FIRST_NAME, C.LAST_NAME, B.COMPANY,A.ITEMNO, A.REV, A.DESCRIP
FROM  ARINVT A
INNER JOIN ARCUSTO B 
  ON A.ARCUSTO_ID = B.ID
INNER JOIN PR_EMP C 
  ON B.AR_PR_EMP_ID = C.ID
WHERE A.ARCUSTO_ID = B.ID 
AND B.AR_PR_EMP_ID = C.ID 
AND A.ONHAND <= 0 
AND A.CUSER7 = 'Y' 
AND NVL(A.PK_HIDE, 'N') <> 'Y'
```

In the second you must wrap  the condition for PK_HIDE in (  )

```
SELECT C.FIRST_NAME, C.LAST_NAME, B.COMPANY,A.ITEMNO, A.REV, A.DESCRIP
FROM  ARINVT A
INNER JOIN ARCUSTO B 
  ON A.ARCUSTO_ID = B.ID
INNER JOIN PR_EMP C 
  ON B.AR_PR_EMP_ID = C.ID
WHERE A.ARCUSTO_ID = B.ID 
AND B.AR_PR_EMP_ID = C.ID 
AND A.ONHAND <= 0 
AND A.CUSER7 = 'Y' 
AND ( A.PK_HIDE = 'N' OR A.PK_HIDE IS NULL)
```

if you dont'use   `( A.PK_HIDE = 'N' OR A.PK_HIDE IS NULL)`   your where condition is equivalent  to

```
WHERE ( A.ARCUSTO_ID = B.ID 
AND B.AR_PR_EMP_ID = C.ID 
AND A.ONHAND <= 0 
AND A.CUSER7 = 'Y' 
AND A.PK_HIDE =  ) 
OR A.PK_HIDE IS NULL
```

that obviuosly produce the wrong result